# How to run rtl8192cu driver in linux with kernel 3.8?

Tags: linux, wifi

I have a trouble with usb WiFi dongle TPLink WN725N (rtl8192cu driver).

Dongle starts, but cannot connect.

Driver in official Realtek site supports only 2.6.18~2.6.38 and 3.0.8 kernels.

Is there a way to run it on kernel 3.8?

dmesg shows this error:

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Comment: I have that dongle and the stock 8192cu driver works for me.  Have you tried initializing and configuring it manually?

Comment: This driver requires a firmware blob that some distros ship in a package separate from the kernel. What distro are you using?

Comment: @bahamat, Fedora 18. Tried on other, to example Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: to people visiting: realtek leaves much to desire. Avoid buying this stick https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to the driver from realtek. I was able to use the mainlined rtl8192cu driver on Linux 3.9.1. Looking at the git log, I see that it was already available since linux-2.6.39.y (`git branch --contains 663dcc73675bd70ee11195ce832b1d1691f967d0`).

`CONFIG_RTL8192CU` must be enabled when building the kernel. Note that `CONFIG_EXPERIMENTAL` needs to be enabled in kernels before 3.6. The resulting module will be called `rtl8192cu`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this variant before, but the result is the same.

Comment: I bought the WN725N v1 which has the rtl8192cu chip. Using the mainlined driver of 3.9(.1 or -rc?) showed issues like packet loss. The driver provided by realtek did not have such issues. Now, are you aware that [a second version of the TP-LINK WN725N](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN725N_v2) exist? That one uses a different driver, the 8188eu.

Comment: Yes, of course. This driver is used by default after installation. But it also does not connect to the network. Thanks for trying to help. I'm tired of the second month to suffer and I bought today a normal adapter.