# Kali Linux Connected to USB Wifi Adapter but unable to enable monitor mode

Tags: debian, wifi

I have a usb wifi adapter TP-Link WN821N , i installed drivers for my wireless card (RTL8192EU) but i am unable to enable monitor mode using my wifi adapter

Comment: welcome to U& L , please connect your Wifi USB and add the output of `lsusb` command

Comment: try this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348777/cant-install-tl-wn821n-v5-drivers-on-kali

Comment: @GAD3R http://i.imgur.com/QYDr7Hz.png

Comment: @GAD3R i successfully connected to the internet. i Installed the drivers and etc but i couldn't get it to monitor mode

Comment: Because it does not support monitor mode. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a VM, depending on the emulation, you have to configure it for the USB stick to be directly visible to it, and install the drivers directly into the VM, and not in the host machine; some emulations mention capturing the USB device/port.

you may be able to put it directly into being used by the VM.

EDIT: I have seen your comments about finally configuring the wifi device.

However this chipset does not support monitor mode.

From the top of my head, only a few select wifi ralink chipset  models support monitor mode for listening, and some atheros models allow for fabricating packets while in monitor mode. The list will change over time, and purpose and as such, I strongly recommend googling around for your particular intended use before buying one USB wifi stick. Avoid nano models, as their effective range is too short for the purpose.

Realtek or Realtek rebranded/compatibles is/are chinese garbage bought at truckload for cents a pop. see this [Wi-Fi problems using ASUS USB-N13 adapter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a virtual machine, you will NEVER get your integrated wireless card as a wireless card inside the virtual machine. It will be detected as a wired ethernet card. It doesn't matter if your vm is bridged or NAT. It doesn't matter what kind of linux you are using (Kali, Debian, Arch or whatever).

To use a wireless card inside your virtual machine, you must use a usb wireless card.

Comment: I understand. There's no way to "SHARE" wifi adapter with the host machine. the built in wifi adapter will never get detected by Virtual Machine.

Comment: Exactly. You can't.

Answer (score 0):

### **NOT VM**

So it depends on the version. We can find this by quick googling. We get `TL-WN821N-V4 does not support Monitor Mode, Only V1/ 2 / 3 not V4.`

We also find a [unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/how-to-run-my-rtl8191su-usb-wifi-adapter-in-monitor-mode-on-linux) link that says your driver doesn't support monitor mode.

My best suggestion is to always (**ALWAYS!!**) check if your adapter and driver supports monitor mode. The stack exchange link has a list of chipsets that support monitor mode.

#### Also

Don't virtualize to set a device in monitor mode. Just not gonna work