# How to disable Wifi Power Save on Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox, power-management

I am running kali with virtualbox and my wifi receiver is a usb adapter which is Asus N10 Nano. I made the settings on virtualbox for making the vb recognize my usb wifi adapter. It works but after like 5min my internet drops. Especially during the updates. I figured it out its because the "Wifi Power Save" option is on. I turned it off and tried again. When i turned it off my wifi turned off at the same time. I tried to turn my wifi on but the Wifi Power Save option turned on itself automatically. The usb icon on bottom is like red-green. It needs to be blinking green to work correctly. If i can turn off the Wifi Power Save mod permamently hopefully its gonna be blinking green. I searched for it, I did almost everything like creating directory as `/etc/pm/power.d/wireless` and editing the file wireless by these commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Then i gave the permission `-x` for it. It didnt work. Sorry if I had mistake while I was writing this. Thanks for helping!

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

It didn't work. In the end `sudo depmod rtl8192cu` output was:
depmod: FATAL: rtl8192cu: not absolute path.

Comment: would you please paste the output of `lspci`?

Comment: You have to answer to posts in the comments. By sheer luck, I was the one approving your edit.My mistake, it should be modprobe. Nevertheless, if it does not work, reboot it. Edited the answer.

Comment: the pen does not come up in lspci, it has to be lsusb. nevertheless already found the chipset in google

Answer (score 2):

The Asus N10 Nano has the Realtek 8192CU chipset. I advise to configure the loading of the required kernel modules using the following procedure.

Create the file `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192cu.conf`, with:

```
options rtl8192cu  rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=1 rtw_ips_mode=1
```

Then do:

```
sudo rmmod rtl8192cu
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
```

If the modprobe does not work, restart the server.

Nevertheless, be warned the Asus N10 Nano is using the rtl8192cu which is a notoriously cheap and buggy chip, notoriously in energy management.

Please do read my answer in this thread, talking also about Asus and the same chipset.

[Wi-Fi problems using ASUS USB-N13 adapter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215)