# Loading new wlan driver

Tags: wifi, usb, kernel-modules, raspberry-pi, realtek

**TL;DR**. Two issues:

1. can't get `wlan0` working,
2. can't get `wpa_supplicant` working.

---

I compiled & installed [kernel 4.4](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) (rev. [eb4d55](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/eb4d55c34018bbb92808264217a0b2857d2b2ae6)) with [revamped rtl8xxxu support](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=26f1fad29ad973b0fb26a9ca3dcb2a73dde781aa) enabled. In order to compile & install kernel, I used [officil steps for raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md).

After booting up with new kernel, I did this:

1. unloaded now-obsolete `8192cu` module:

   ```
   sudo modprobe -r 8192cu
   ```
2. loaded newly available `rtl8xxxu` module:

   ```
   sudo modprobe rtl8892xxxu
   ```
3. confirmed this via `dmesg`:

   ```
   [ 1225.566010] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl8192cu
   [ 1362.505013] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
   ```

However, I have 2 problems:

1. I can't seem to get `wlan0` up:

   ```
   $ sudo ifdown wlan0
   ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured
   $ sudo ifup wlan0
   $ sudo ifup wlan0
   ifup: interface wlan0 already configured
   ```
2. I can't seem to get `wpa_supplicant` working, likely because `wlan0` is *down*:

   ```
   $ sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c my_wpa.conf 
   Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
   Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
   nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
   Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
   wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
   ```

This is my `/etc/netword/interfaces/`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

## About my environment

**Stock version of `wpa_supplicant`:**

```
$ wpa_supplicant -v 
wpa_supplicant v2.3
Copyright (c) 2003-2014, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
```

**Contents of `wpa_supplicant.conf`:**

```
$ cat wpa_supplicant.conf 
network={
  ssid="my_network_name"
  psk="my_password"
}
```

**List of USB devices:**

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Distro version:**

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.5+ #7 Thu Mar 17 11:48:18 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

**Loaded kernel modules:**

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rtl8xxxu               53252  0 
mac80211              602908  1 rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              488954  1 mac80211
rfkill                 21277  1 cfg80211
bcm2835_gpiomem         3823  0 
snd_bcm2835            27597  0 
bcm2835_wdt             4133  0 
snd_pcm                92845  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              22312  1 snd_pcm
snd                    66956  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
uio_pdrv_genirq         3654  0 
uio                    10166  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
```