# ath10k firmware not updated for 168c:0041

Tags: debian, wifi

I'm running a Debian 8 system with an Atheros `ath10k` chipset. My wireless drivers won't activate, forcing me to use a USB dongle.

It appears the drivers included with my kernel don't support my device ID: `lspci -nn | grep -i net` returns

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)
```

and `modinfo ath10k_pci` only lists `168c:003c` and `168c:003e` as device IDs, not the `168c:0041` listed next to my wireless card.

How do I get my card to work?

I'm using a Lenovo G50-80 laptop.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux hamming 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4 (2016-02-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should also work for `168c:0040` and `168c:0042`.

You need to grab backported drivers and firmware for your card.

First, the drivers. Download the [latest stable release](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/) of the backported wireless compatibility drivers; grab the `.tar.xz` version from the latest subfolder on the list (doesn't matter if it's more recent than your kernel). Put it in a directory of your choice, and then run

```
tar Jxvf backports-<whatever>.tar.xz
```

`cd` into the resulting directory and run

```
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

and then

```
sudo reboot
```

to reboot.

On startup (when the screen is showing black and white monospace text; i.e. before the desktop environment shows up), you'll notice some error messages which contain paths. The paths will contain the letters `QCA`, a four-digit number, followed by `/hw` and a decimal. Write down those two numbers. (If you miss them, run `dmesg | grep QCA` to see them again.) We'll say the path contains `QCA6174/hw2.1`.

Next, the firmware. You'll need to clone the [Github repository](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware) housing the updated firmware:

```
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
```

`cd` into the resulting directory (`ath10k-firmware`). Then `cd` into the directories on that path you noted earlier (say `QCA6174/hw2.1`).

Now, this directory will contain a few files, one of which will start with `firmware`. (Let's say it's `firmware-5.bin_<garbage>`.) You'll copy that into `/lib/firmware/QCA6174/hw2.1` (again, substitute the paths you noted), removing the garbage:

```
sudo cp firmware-5.bin_<garbage> /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
```

(You might need to `sudo mkdir` the directories along the destination path if they don't already exist. If `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174` exists, you should probably rename it to `QCA6174.old` to preserve it.)

If there are any other files in the directory (other than `notice.txt_<garbage>`), copy them over as well. In my case, I had to copy two files, `board.bin` and `board-2.bin`:

```
sudo cp board* /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/
```

Then reboot. You should be done! (Your system might complain about missing some `cal-pci` file on startup, but that hasn't caused issues for me.)

Comment: It would be **much** easier to just download and install an updated linux-image and firmware-atheros package from debian testing or unstable.   You can even add testing and/or unstable to your sources.list and (as long as you have `APT::Default-Release "stable";` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`or  file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`) there is no risk of accidentally installing stuff from them - apt will only install from them when you explicitly tell it to, with `-t testing` or `-t unstable`.   Also, there's always http://backports.debian.org/

Comment: It must be the board-2.bin with the newest stable backports that allows that firmware to work.  Back when I got this card going we used backports-20151120 with firmware from https://github.com/atondwal/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/ath10k/QCA6164/hw2.1  @cas I doubt debian has the board-2.bin as it has only been a month since Kalle put it on his github and the firmware-5 file is probably an older version