# How to install TPLink721n on debian stretch?

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, drivers, debian-installer

I installed debian jessie 2 months ago using an unofficial nonfree cd-image. With that my USB wifi stick worked flawlessly. I moved to version "stretch", I was unable to find nonfree version, and I cant make the OS to see any wifi networks. I added `rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw` to the bootdrive, becouse the installer said so. After that the installation went great (did not show to add that firmware) but still the wifi does not work.

Can you help me with that? How to install the TPlink 721n's driver? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: to people visiting: realtek leaves much to desire. Avoid buying this stick https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution
enetrinh the `lsusb` command to know what is my chipset it was AR9271
After that I searched for this chipset and this site showed the [**solution**](https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc):

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-atheros
```