# Network interface on Linux Mint 18 not working properly (RTL8821AE)

Tags: linux-mint, network-interface

I bought a pretty new laptop, with Windows 10 installed when I bought it. On Windows everything was working fine, yet was not happy about Windows and I decided to install Linux Mint 18 (xfce).

Mint on my laptop is working fine, except for the built-in WiFi adapter. I tried quite some things to fix it, but with no succes.

The adapter is connected to wifi and for a few minutes it works fine. After that, the adapter can't find a DNS anymore. Pinging stops working and I basically have no internet.

Recently, I discovered that the problem can be (temporary) be solved by using:

```
~ $ sudo ifdown wlp2s0 && sudo ifup wlp2s0
```

The command gives this error:

```
Unkown interface wlp2s0
```

After that, the adapter works fine for a few minutes. It seemed to me that I was supposed to manually configure the network interface.
So I added the following to the /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet static
address <IP here>
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway <IP here>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Now I get these errors:

```
ifdown: interface wlp2s0 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up wlp2s0.
```

Again, the adapter works fine for a few minutes.
But when I reboot my laptop, the adapter is not being recognized anymore.

Is there any way to fix the problem permanently?

Laptop: Toshiba Sattelite C55D-C
Network adapter: RTL8821AE

Comment: Realtek wifi chipsets are junk. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with `dnsmasq` in Mint 18 and 18.1

Just edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
and change `dns=dnsmasq` to `#dns=dnsmasq`.

easy as that :p