# TP-Link WiFi USB adapter keeps dropping connection immediately on Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, drivers, usb

`dmesg` output when I try connecting via gnome desktop:

```
[ 4162.708769] R8188EU: INFO assoc success
[ 4165.713425] R8188EU: INFO ap recv disassoc reason code(2) sta:f8:3d:ff:ed:3b:b7
[ 4165.716173] R8188EU: INFO sta recv deauth reason code(6) sta:f8:3d:ff:ed:3b:b7, ignore = 0
[ 4165.720651] R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc
```

New install of Debian 8, downloaded the Linux driver from TP-Link site. `make`,`make install` wlan0 appears available

```
# ifconfig wlan0 
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:e3:27:15:fd:03  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:232 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5320 (5.1 KiB)  TX bytes:6280 (6.1 KiB)
```

Anyone know what's wrong and how to fix?

EDIT:

tried to compile from source and this is what I see now after reboot (Wireless access point not showing in wireless network list so still not able to connect to internet via WiFi):

```
[    8.179429] EEPROM ID = 0x8129
[    8.180503] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
[    8.454849] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    8.517110] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    8.517119] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    8.517123] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    8.517131] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.517138] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz, 92000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.517144] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.517149] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.517155] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    8.517160] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    8.517165] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.517170] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.548684] r8188eu 2-1:1.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin
[    8.548720] R8188EU: Firmware Version 11, SubVersion 1, Signature 0x88e1
[    8.926288] MAC Address = 60:e3:27:15:fd:03
[    8.930721] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   10.238268] R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc
[   10.335372] R8188EU: INFO assoc success
[   10.335443] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   10.794016] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[   10.794025] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[   10.794030] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[   10.794034] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[   10.826250] FS-Cache: Loaded
[   10.845544] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[   10.903147] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
[   14.360757] tg3 0000:3f:00.0: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[   15.754090] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

EDIT:

output of `cat` and `lsusb`

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 
0
# lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Try to compile the driver from git https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

Comment: Is your router/wireless access point using WEP or WPA or what? Some WEP implementations are really lacking these days, and cause the symptom you describe.

Comment: It's WPA so it is.

Comment: @GAD3R compiled from source and installed. Still no go - see dmesg output above.

Comment: return the realtek adapter while you can or give it to the dog. See my answer here. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` and `lsusb` ?

Comment: @GAD3R see edit.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Strange had no trouble with it before and also had it recommended for linux machines.

Comment: You pay what you get. There is no doubt they are picked up quickly by Linux machines, however they are buggy. They are commonly found because they are (very) cheap - vendors pay cents for them. I wont go over again what I mentioned in my post(s). I recommend ralink or atheros, just be on lookup some atheros models are not compatible with Linux.

Comment: Disable the IPV6 https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6

Comment: @GAD3R disabled via grub but still not detecting any wifi network.