# Constant internet interruptions

Tags: internet

Internet connectivity on my desktop (debian jessie) seems to constantly fall away.
I had a direct ethernet connection, in which case I had internet around 95% of the time, however I'm on wifi right now, and seem to have internet around 1% of the time.
I don't actually lose the connection.
I vaguely remember finding out my desktop uses the same gate as my modem(?), but didn't find out how to change that and ended up forgetting about it because the ethernet worked mostly well. Internet on my other devices works as expected.

I use a Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
Turning off IPv6 didn't work

dump:

```
[    1.444577] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[    1.447259] rtl8188ee 0000:04:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[    1.448713] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    1.448833] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[    1.444577] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[    1.447259] rtl8188ee 0000:04:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[    1.448713] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    1.448833] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[    1.436765] rtl8188ee 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0100 -> 0103)
```

Comment: Could you please share what is your Wi-Fi card and see if anything about it is dumped to the logs?

Comment: How can I find those logs?

Comment: Just use `dmesg` command and try to find relevant information there.

Comment: @styrofoamfly I've added some stuff, but really don't know what to look for otherwise.

Comment: How close are you to the AP, and what frequency are you using (2GHz or 5GHz), and are there any walls or anything between you and the access point?

Comment: @cutrightjm A few meter, there are no walls in the way, and my laptop has wifi from farther away.

Comment: Please read. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215