# Debian 9 intermittent wifi

Tags: debian, wifi

Fresh clean install of Debian 9 on Asus laptop.
Had to install realtek non-free firmware for network on install.
rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin was requested and installed https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-realtek this package.

Symptoms;
Wifi will periodically time out and no browser/cli will have internet access, often after 3-5 minutes this connection will come back and pages will load as normal. The machine stays connected to the network, it doesnt get kicked off just stalls and times out.

Problem does not persist when running windows on the machine, and furthermore does not persist with other flavours of linux, ie kali/tails I have tested.

Comment: Realtek is no good. Buy a ralink. For more details please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: Thank you for that very informative tho disappointing post. I was hoping there would be a solution of loading either a newer version or different firmware for the wifi module to work, as kali/tails seem to have no problem holding down a connection therefore there must be a software solution that doesnt include buying an external usb wifi adaptor.

Comment: Nah. Some configurations/ some Windows drivers may mask the bugs at the cost of subpar performance and no energy savings, however the bugs are still there. As I said in the post the Chinese make that POS by the truckload costing cents.

Comment: That is indeed a very valid point re drivers masking bugs perhaps I am trying to delay the inevitable and a good solid usb wifi adapter is the easiest solution sadly