# Weak wifi signal in Debian 9

Tags: debian, wifi, realtek, hp

I have a Notebook HP G5 240 with RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter Driver installed (`firmware-realtek_20161130-3_all.deb`, and `firmware-linux` `firmware-linux-nonfree` , `firmware-misc-nonfree`)

The thing is that WiFi works well when Notebook is close to router (1 to 2 meters). But greater distances no have wifi signal (another Windows-Notebook can connect to 30 meters) Another (related) thing is the follow [image: mensaje] Suggestions? 
Solutions? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not use images where photos would work. The text is not that big.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least 3 questions in there; I will try to address those with the data you gave us.

1) Wifi stability

Your wifi is a Realtek, which is known to have stability problems. see this link [Wi-Fi problems using ASUS USB-N13 adapter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215)

The  RTL8723BE also operates only in the 2.4GHz band, which in most of the civilised world, including Europe and Spain/Portugal (olá), has too much interference.

I would recommend buying a dual frequency ralink chipset wifi pen for Linux. Replacing your internal wifi card in an HP notebook with a noname wifi card usually is not possible in HP brand notebooks due to the firmware whitelisting hardware.

You have not told us if your wireless AP is capable of working in the 5GHz band; if not I strongly recommend you to buy one.

Comparing wifi between brands/equipments is not an exact science, and different firmwares/makes/antenna lengths/transmission power/transmission frequency *can and will exhibit different behaviours*.

You also have not told us your country. Changing from the wifi country mode operation from US to ES, for instance, will allow it to transmit at greater potency for several brands.

The wifi problem is too complex and got too many variables to continue addressing it here.

2) the missing bluetooth firmware error in the photo

Your bluetooth firmware is missing at the time of that error. If you intend to use it, you also have to install the appropriate package. However, it seems `firmware-realtek_20161130-3` is supposed to have that file, and as such I suspect the photo is before you installed it.

3) The SB.PCI.... error.

That is a known UEFI/firmware bug. Upgrading your HP firmware *might* solve it.

Comment: Please open new questions with further specific doubts; do not add new questions here.