# USB wifi adapter for kali linux 2017.1 in raspberry pi 3

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, hardware

I'm thinking of buying-

1) Panda PAU05-[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00EQT0YK2/?tag=whtnb-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EQT0YK2)

2)The Detroit DIY Electronics Wifi Antenna For Raspberry Pi-
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00H95C0A2/?tag=whtnb-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H95C0A2)

I would like to know if they are compatible with updated kali linux.

Comment: I *think* the edits I made to the question qualify it for reopening. It is not a matter of what is the best, but if they are compatible now.

Answer (score 2):

The panda pau05 is a nano 2.4Ghz usb realtek adapter, the 2nd a 2.4GHz  ralink too.

Both are compatible with the Linux kernel, and conversely with Kali Linux. However:

I do not recommend buying neither a nano wifi adapter the range is too low, especially for using in AP mode (the photo of that one does not show an external antena connector).

nor do I recommend buying a wifi adapter  with a realtek chipset. They are too buggy, and give loads of problems. see [Wi-Fi problems using ASUS USB-N13 adapter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215)

If I am not mistaken, the Detroit DIY Electronics Wifi Antenna also uses a very old ralink chipset.

As for the frequency, you are much better with an adapter that supports dual frequency, either for ethical hacking, AP mode or escaping the terrible noise in residential areas.

As for the external antennas, 2dB gain is nothing special.

For that kind of money I would buy a ralink dual frequency chipset based adapter in aliexpress that is also supported by linux and works so much better. I actually have two and they work quite well. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/YOC-300Mbps-Dual-Band-2-4Ghz-5Ghz-Wireless-N-USB-WiFi-Adapter-802-11-a-b/32773231343.html

Be aware that the recommended chipset for wifi ethical hacking is the atheros chipset, but it will cost more. The linux compatile ones are capable of both doing monitor mode AND packet injection.

So I recommend a dual frequency ralink for price or atheros as the expensive alternative.

I would not buy neither of the adapters you mention.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I just wanted to know that that will the second one work fine with kali linux and could u recommend me a good and affordable Atheros based adapter.

Comment: The only atheros I have here came with the notebook. Unfortunately, I do not have the time to search one for you. Ask for one in a kali forum, you might have better luck.