# Debian stretch failed to load firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw (-2)

Tags: debian, boot, firmware

I'm getting this error in `Debian stretch` during the boot process

```
[ 26.390311] r8169 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw (-2)
```

After that I continues the boot and works fine. Is there any firmware or driver missing?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

After hours of searching on different resources i ended up solving the problem which was caused  by a missing of `firmware-realtek` the realtek driver .

The missing of this firmware can throw different errors  prefixed by `rtl_nic/`
to solve this simply add the official repository [**Debian firmware-realtek**](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-realtek)
to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by  running this command

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and make sure you are selecting the right **Distro**

your ***source.list*** should look like this:

```
#realtek firmware
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free
deb-src  http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free
```

After that  install realtek firmware

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/firmware-failed-to-load-rtl_nic-rtl8168g-2-fw-2-a-4175555113/

Comment: what if we dont have internet on that pc...? can we download using another pc for specifically that file and then use the USB stick and go on to the shell (by recovery mode) and ... how to deploy that firmware manually anyway ? @lotfio

Comment: @gumuruh, you definitely can. If you download the firmware-realtek deb file to a USB drive, you may have to mount the USB drive and change your directory to it, but then you can install it with:    
sudo dpkg -i firmware-realtek*.deb

Answer (score 1):

As of "Bookworm", the /etc/apt/sources.list will already contain entries for the "non-free-firmware" repositories.
[image]

But you will still need to install the realtek firmware.

`apt update && apt -y install firmware-realtek`

And note that there is separate firmware for rtl8723cs-bt.