# Debian stretch does not boot

Tags: debian, boot, firmware, realtek

During boot process I receive the following message and boot stops.

`firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw (-2)`

I can't do anything.

Comment: That's almost certainly not the problem, since that should still let you boot (albeit without network). Have you tried booting in recovery mode?

Comment: I tried recovery mode, then i choose the default mode but the same error is appeared again. Please note that i am relatively new on linux

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384403/debian-stretch-failed-to-load-firmware-rtl-nic-rtl8168g-3-fw-2 >

Comment: @dimt172z So do you mean recovery mode works but default mode doesn't?

Comment: Yes, i can only use recovery mode as a terminal. I tried to install via terminal the firmware-realtec but is doesn't work.  It seems that i have a network problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that a driver software is missing. More specifically, it seems that a network driver (Realtek driver) is causing the issue.
The strange part is that such errors do not affect the boot process. The operating system should boot and you should get a tty.

Some solutions that I may suggest,

1. Be sure that you haven't changed anything in your harware (ex. add a new NIC)
2. Boot from a previous kernel version, if there is any on your grub options
3. Boot from a previous kernel version, if there is any on your grub options, in safe mode. If the system boots, you may look for errors in `/var/log/syslog` or using the command `dmesg`.
4. Restore your kernel with the process described in the accepted answer of [this so question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels).
5. Boot from a live cd, make a backup of your files/configurations and install Debian again! If it fails during network setup step, you may have a failed hardware.