# Debian boot failure - unable to load firmware patch rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw (-2)

Tags: debian, boot

When attempting to boot Debian, it stops at the following message. It seems to me the crucial line of failure is "Unable to load firmware patch rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw (-2)". The lines under that seem like it's unable because it can't connect to the internet.

[image: Phone Screenshot]

This machine has started up before. This boot problem came into existence after I had to reset the computer because of an infinity loop in a subthread, and it didn't allow me to switch process anymore. It also used to be able to connect to the internet and install packages/use firefox just fine.

Possible related to [Debian stretch failed to load firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw (-2)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384403/debian-stretch-failed-to-load-firmware-rtl-nic-rtl8168g-3-fw-2), and I'd love to attempt the same fix. However, that failure was non-lethal and the user was able to boot into debian and fix it. My problem happens at a moment I cannot use Ctrl+Alt+FX to get into a terminal, and it does not progress beyond this screen.

Any other google results I got also had the user being able to boot into GUI/Terminal just fine.

My apologies for the screenshot being a bit out of focus. The screen also started flickering, which made it hard to get a good photo.

I don't have an installer USB, but I could make one.

I'm not that experienced with unix in general or debian, so please keep that in mind for answers.

Anybody got pointers how to recover this installation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inability to connect to the internet should not cause the system to fail quite that drastically. I think you may have other problems, and their messages might have already scrolled off the screen. You could use `Shift` + `PgUp`/`PgDown` keys to scroll the messages backwards some amount; that might allow you to see the earliest abnormal messages.

At the top of your screenshot, there is a message:

```
You are in rescue mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view 
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
boot into default mode.
```

Normally, there should be a prompt to enter a root password after this text.
But in your case, there is another message:

```
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for details.

Press Enter to continue.
```

This means the system was going to allow you rescue mode access, but there does not seem to be a valid root password available. You'll need to fix that first.

Reboot the system, interrupt GRUB when it displays the menu and press E to edit the boot options. Move to the `kernel` line and add `init=/bin/bash` to the end of it. Then press the appropriate key (indicated on the screen) to boot the system with the temporarily-modified options.

This should bring the system up to a point where only the root filesystem is mounted, and even that is in read-only mode, but you get a `#` root prompt straight away.

First, get the root filesystem into writeable state:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then, use the `passwd` command to set a new password for root. It will prompt you to enter the new password twice. If you plan to use characters that are not numbers or US-ASCII letters, use the command prompt to test the keyboard mapping before setting the password: it's possible that the keyboard mapping of your choice is not in effect and you're falling back to US English default layout in this mode.

Once you've successfully set a root password, it is time to restart the system again.
But because of the special way used to start the system, some special steps are needed.

```
mount -o remount,ro /
sync
reboot -f
```

On next boot, the system will probably again drop into rescue mode, but now there should be a prompt to enter a root password. Enter the root password you previously set, and you should get the root prompt. Finally you can follow the suggestion to use the `journalctl -xb` command to view the system log.

The logs will normally contain a lot of informational (non-error) messages. You should find the earliest error message; that is probably the root cause of the boot process going off the rails.

---

An alternative method for gaining access to a system that has severe problems is to boot from an installation media (e.g. your installation USB stick) using the `rescue` boot parameter. The installer will present the standard language/keyboard layout questions, and then switch into a special rescue mode that attempts to detect an existing Debian installation, mount its disks and provide you with a command prompt + a set of tools to fix things.

---

Oh, and to fix your missing Realtek firmware: use another computer to grab the [firmware-realtek .deb package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/firmware-realtek/download), save it on some removable media, move it to your computer and use e.g. `dpkg -i firmware-realtek*.deb` to install it.

Comment: I got into terminal access again. Thanks for that, anyway. The real problem is still out there, but at least I can start googling for that again.

Comment: Added the instructions for downloading & installing your missing `firmware-realtek` package. But I'll be surprised if the lack of firmware is the only reason for your system crashing into rescue mode at boot.

Comment: It's one of them. I managed to find that one through the linked question. I had to download another one through https://joshtronic.com/2017/11/06/fixed-radeon-kernel-modesetting-for-r600-or-later-requires-firmware-amd-graphics/ . I also had to reconfigure network connections before doing all that ( https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration gave me most for that, but am still working on that one.) I'll update the question with the entire journey.

Comment: I made some progress and can attempt login through the GUI. However, it just returns me to the login screen again. Could this have anything to do with the fact that I installed with the root account disabled and with the user account as legal sudo'er, and stuff got mixed up re-enabling the root account ?

Comment: @JaccovanDorp Please do not update the question so much. Write an answer to your own question if you want to report what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the definition of your interfaces in  `/etc/network/interfaces` from `auto` to `allow-hotplug`. It will stop it hanging.

As in:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

To modify the file, you have either to boot in single mode, or easier for a newbie, booting from a live image in a pen.

Comment: That would be very nice, if I could access a terminal. Or can I type that in the grub-terminal ?

Comment: I've attempted to boot in single mode(after googling it), but that fails with the same problem. As in booting from a live image, you mean another copy installed on a USB ? I've tried that before, but that wouldn't boot on this (rather ancient) machine.

Comment: Burn a DVD then. Although I suspect you must be making some mistake jumping to single user mode.

Comment: I'm afraid I might have not clarified enough. I got an installation USB now, but I should install debian itself on the USB so I can run a terminal from there ?

Comment: Since I've got a newer version of Debian, I need to use enp0s1, or some variant of that one. For the rest, this seems to have gotten me a bit closer, with some changes. I'll update the question with my results after I can boot without recovery mode again.

Comment: Yeah, new naming scheme for interfaces. it is just an example.

Comment: Well, I didn't know there was a new naming scheme, so I was googling something like "why dont I have eth0 but it works under windows dual boot". Never underestimate how little new people know. I stubled across the new scheme by accident.

Comment: AntiX here in the desktop and CentOS/RH servers with the new naming scheme disabled