# WiFi card tremendously slow

Tags: fedora, wifi, network-interface

I recently purchased an ASUS PCE-AC51 Wireless PCI-E Adapter for my PC and didn't have any driver problems on my Windows 10 (works as expected).

If I try to use it on my Linux (Fedora 26; 4.13.5-200.fc26.x86_64; GNOME 3.24.2) I have a tremendous performance drop. My connection is *never* faster than 100 Kb/s and it is simply useless.

The driver from the official ASUS website is out dated and I was not able to compile/install it.

I have tried installing `rtl8821ae` from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) and succeeded, but still performance is not improving.

Here are some more info:

```
$ lspci | grep -i wireless
1f:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

$ lspci -vv -s 1f:00.0 
1f:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 86dd
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort+ <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 62
    Region 0: I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at fd500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae

$ lspci -n -s 1f:00.0
1f:00.0 0280: 10ec:8812 (rev 01)
```

Does anyone know what could be the cause of the issue I am dealing with?

PS.
If I connect with LAN cable it works also as expected.

Comment: Feed it to the dogs, or return it while you can. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Answer (score 0):

The Wireless problem is not specific to the OS 'version' (RedHat/Ubuntu) but more specific to the Generic Linux Kernel Version Number and the "mod" (linux module) loaded?

This problem related to safety of high(er) (5G 802.11ac) frequency wireless depending on the location of the computer in your room or safety of this location in terms of (auto detected) wireless signal power signal safety?

To see more details about your card you might want to try type

```
lshw -C network
```

you should see something that looks like this...

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=5.4.0-59-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:36 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:
```

to see the specific "module" that is connected to your linux kernel you can type...

```
modinfo rtl8821ae
```

you should see something similar to this.. (however my wireless is also running slow and has stability issues as well (around 10 Mbps download or upload)

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-59-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_29.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8821ae 802.11ac PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     AxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxA
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008821sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008812sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8821ae
vermagic:       5.4.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
```

I did remove some of the serial numbers and crypt o signatures and keys from the above for privacy reasons...

I'm not sure what the problem is exactly with the drivers but hopefully the revision will be updated in the next "RealTek" wireless module firmware release.

I think they are taking the correct approach to not write drivers and release them on their website but rather get a signature and combine these with a module that is released into the mainstream Linux Kernel Builds.  The company RealTek (seems cool to me) and is Taiwanese located on the island in a very elite "Asian Silicon Valley".  They are probably (are) working hard to support as many wireless 802.11ac (new IEEE standard?) technical details as possible.

It maybe best to only command line "update" the software with a major linux kernel release and just deal with the slower wireless speeds?