# TP Link Wifi dongle connectivity drops after 12 hours on Linux Kernel 2.6

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, embedded, access-point

I am using USB WiFi dongle (TP Link) to connect my custom device to the Access Point. Upon device boot up, the connection and speed is normal. After about 12 hours, the network connectivity drops and is never re-established.

I see the following error message in

```
R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc

R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc

R8188EU: INFO sta recv deauth reason code(2) sta:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, ignore = 0

R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc

R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc

R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc

R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc
```

The Linux Kernel used is 2.6.36 and wpa_suplicant version used is 2.6 (wext driver). The authentication mechanism is WPA2 / PSK.

The cycle repeats upon device reboot

The other devices such as Laptops and mobile phones connected to this access point works fine without any interruptions.

Thanks

Comment: Realtek-based chips are full of bugs. get another chipset. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Rui.
Could you please suggest an alternate wifi-usb-adapter which has a different chipset? Almost all the usb adapters available in the market are having Realtek chips.