# How to get the wifi working with r8188eu driver on my raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, shell, wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Hy there,
I am having problem in connecting my raspberry pi to a wifi dongle.
I have followed a lot of tutorials from internet but no success so far.

My WIFI dongle can scan the networks but it's not connecting to any network.Here is what my configuration file looks like

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev 
country=GB 
update_config=1


network={
    ssid="noname"
    #psk="zong4gisbest"
    psk=ead5b0b7e82e1a68f01e9a17a2a7719ec24575c89bb5b5805e4ae49c80daa983 }
```

Here are the results of my commands on Raspbian

```
iwconfig

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188ETV 
Wireless LAN 802.11n Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514   
Fast Ethernet Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can you please help me resolving the issue?

thanks

Comment: realtek will not provide a reliable connection. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit your `wpa_supplicant.conf` , change the following lines:

```
network={
    ssid "noname"
    psk"zong4gisbest"
```

to:

```
network={
    ssid="noname"
    #psk="zong4gisbest"
    psk=ead5b0b7e82e1a68f01e9a17a2a7719ec24575c89bb5b5805e4ae49c80daa983
}
```

save then run

```
wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -D wext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
dhclient wlan0
```

The error:

> nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands

mean that the standard nl80211 doesn't support your device , you should use the old driver `wext`.

To correctly set up your `wpa_supplicant.conf` , it is better to use the `wpa_passphrase` command:

```
wpa_passphrase YOUR-SSID YOUR-PASSWORD >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

To automatically connect to your AP after restart edit the `wlan0` interface on your `/etc/network/interfaces` as follow:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Tried using 
wpa_passphrase YOUR-SSID YOUR-PASSWORD >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

But here is the error
https://imgur.com/a/TudGH

Comment: after saving, when i tried>>wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B

I see this error now
https://imgur.com/a/wrDrh

Comment: @JazibHassan Please edit your question with the output of `lsusb` , a text output is better than an image.

Comment: @JazibHassan use `wext` driver , see my update

Comment: What's wext? I am sorry, i am kinda new here!

Comment: i have update my answer , what is the output of `lsmod | grep r8188` ?

Comment: here is the output:

r8188eu               425544  0
cfg80211              525806  1 r8188eu

Comment: Hey bro, it just worked. I thought, you asked me to use two different commands
1>>wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -D wext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B 
2>>dhclient wlan0

I didn't know that it's a single command. Now it worked great. I am doing ssh using wifi now. thanks bro

Comment: However each time i restart the pi, i have to do that command to enable wifi. is there any hack which can do the job? thanks again

Comment: I tried adding this code before . After i rebooted, the raspberrypi was not responding. I had to reinstall the OS. Shall i give it a try again?

Comment: see [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up) create a script which contain the `wpa_supplicant` and the `dhclient` command

Comment: @JazibHassan It is better to ask a new question to connect with wpa_supplicant at boot , you will get some good suggestions

Comment: *`nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands` => you should use the old driver `wext`*: does it mean, that I cannot use AP mode `CONFIG_AP=y` and thus need to use `hostapd`?

Comment: @pevik You need to check if your wifi device support the AP mode through `sudo iw list |grep -A15 'Supported interface modes'` , You should see `AP` listed , if not you can't use the wifi device as hotspot AP.

Answer (score 0):

simple:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/raw/c83976d1dfb4793893158461430261562b3a5bf0/rtl8188eufw.bin  -O /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin
```

and replug, see

> https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/764#issuecomment-73355704