# Have to run insmod for rtl8812au after each boot

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, dkms

I use the `rtl8812au` driver for my wifi adapter. I have dkms setup so that after each kernel upgrade, it gets compiled. Here are the commands I ran to set that up:

```
DRV_NAME=rtl8812AU
DRV_VERSION=4.3.14
mkdir /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
git archive driver-${DRV_VERSION} | tar -x -C /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
dkms add -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
dkms build -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
dkms install -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
```

Now, after each reboot, my wifi adapter is disabled and to get it working again, I have to go back to the source directory of rtl8812au driver (I go to the original dir, not the dkms-made one), ensure that make has been run for this kernel, and run `insmod 8812au.ko`. At this point, my adapter fires up and works until the next boot.

How to fix dkms for this driver?

Comment: avoid realtek https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: I have no problem with it when the kernel mod is running. I haven't always had this issue where I have to manually do insmod. I think it's a command I'm missing. There's nothing wrong with the driver for my adapter.

Comment: does adding the text 8812au to /etc/modules fixes your problem?

Comment: Just for reference, dkms is responsible to (re)build a driver for new kernels, but not to load this driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat /usr/src/8812au-4.3.14/dkms.conf 
PACKAGE_NAME="rtl8812AU"
PACKAGE_VERSION="#MODULE_VERSION#"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="8812au"
MAKE="'make'"
CLEAN="'make' clean"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
AUTOINSTALL="YES"
```

But I use git clone.  And I rename /usr/src/rtl8812AU to /usr/src/8812au-4.3.14/

```
sudo dkms add -m 8812au -v 4.3.14
sudo dkms install -m 8812au -v 4.3.14
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
```

The drivername is 8812au not rtl8812AU.  You need depmod -a because  `modinfo 8812au | grep dep
depends:        cfg80211`

The modul needs another modul as dependency.

Comment: I reinstalled the dkms module and it's working fine again. This is good info too and would have lead to the same thing so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub page: [gordboy](https://github.com/gordboy) has three repositories for Realtek 8812AU drivers.

Currently, the newest is [8812au-5.9](https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au-5.9.3.2)

Clone the git repository, cd into its folder and type:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Everything is compiled and installed automatically (thanks [gordboy](https://github.com/gordboy)!)