# How to get D-link DWA-131 Wireless-N Nano USB Adapter work on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, wifi, drivers, usb, network-interface

I am on CentOS 7. I have **D-link DWA-131 Wireless-N USB Nano *Hardware revision* E1**  adapter. I have downloaded and compiled it's drivers from ftp://files.dlink.com.au/products/DWA-131/REV_E/Drivers/DWA-131_Linux_driver_v4.3.1.1.zip. After installing and inserting the module **8192eu.ko** my device is detected as **USB Ethernet**. How can i get it recognized as a wireless device, so that I can connect to a wireless network **abc** having password **12345678**.

result of **uname -a** is

```
Linux linux-centos 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

result of **ifconfig -a** is

```
enp0s20u3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 54:2a:a2:47:dd:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
       inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
       inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
       loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
       RX packets 7729  bytes 664831 (649.2 KiB)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 7729  bytes 664831 (649.2 KiB)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p4p2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
       ether f8:ca:b8:06:55:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
       RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:1c:39:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:1c:39:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::374e:5cb2:ec50:9c4d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 78:0c:b8:36:8e:31  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 122333  bytes 155288565 (148.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 84226  bytes 10510089 (10.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**enp0s20u3** is my USB device. It only shows up when I load **8192eu.ko** using **modprobe** or **insmod**.

[image: Device detected as USB Ethernet instead of Wireless]

Device shown as wifi is 'internal wifi', but, the USB device is detected as USB Ethernet.

Comment: realtek based chipset products are junk https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have another realtek based usb wifi device, and I am able to run it on linux (ubuntu and centos7)... for ubuntu I had to compile drivers, but it is working fine... its rtl8192cu based, the as in link you posted... it's drivers can be downloaded from (https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes)... I am not able to install **8192eu** on centos 7, as compiled drivers give the above mentioned problem

Comment: Nobody said they do not work at all. Just that they suck as a product.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Can you suggest any other vendor or product which can work as usb wifi antenna, which is considered good for linux.

Comment: read my answer in the link of my 1st comment; it is not clear cut I am afraid....

Answer (score 0):

For me it works only immediately after reloading the module:

```
modprobe -r rtl8xxxu; sleep 2; modprobe rtl8xxxu
```

(connection in NetworkManager pre-configured)

Besides I have additional options for it:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
options rtl8xxxu ht40_2g=1 dma_aggregation=1 rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0
```