# /lib/modules/4.14.0-kali1-amd64/build doesn't exist when I try to install rtl8814au driver

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, kernel-modules

I can't install the `rtl8814au` driver in Kali Linux running kernel 4.14.0.

When I run `make` in the `rtl8814au` directory, it outputs this:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.14.0-kali1-amd64/build M=/rtl8814au  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.0-kali1-amd64/build: No such a file....
Makefile:1699: ....
```

Any idea?

**SOLUTION**

apt install linux-headers-xxx didn't work for me because it was no longer 
available in the repositories. So I downloaded these from http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/ and its dependencies that shell told me in warnings.

After that, I could play "make" command and worked for me perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't possibly have tried _everything_. What have you actually tried? Please edit your question to tell us before it gets closed either as unclear or "you shouldn't be using Kali".

Comment: You should install your kernel sources.

Comment: if you are able, get another wifi chipset https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: @peterh the full kernel sources aren’t necessary, the “headers” packages provide all that’s needed (and set the `build` symlinks up correctly).

Comment: @StephenKitt Right. The question arises, why should this question be closed as kali :-)

Comment: @peterh, indeed; I voted to keep it open.

Comment: @StephenKitt, peterh well, I voted to close mainly because of the "I've tried everything" coupled with the omission of a list of things the OP had tried. IME this is suggestive of a non-technical user. Happy to vote to re-open (so that's three of us) if you think it's a reasonable question.

Comment: @roaima I'm sorry if you have been insulted by my question. Nobody knows at the beggining, that's why people use this forum to post their worries. I'am using Kali just to learn security methods because I am bored developing. Thanks anyway for your help and opinion

Comment: Not at all insulted. Everyone does have to start learning somewhere, but Kali is not that place.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-amd64`:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-amd64
```

Comment: Thank you @StephenKitt. It didnt work at all. I needed the "linux-headers" but not with apt install. I had to download in [link](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/) . Then I searched for my kernel and all its dependencies. Thanks a lot