# Problem with TP-Link TL-WN722N v2 with putting it in monitor mode! Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I cannot put TP-Link TL-WN722N v2 in monitor mode. I've tried this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bc
sudo rmmod r8188eu.ko
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus
cd rtl8188eus
sudo -i
echo "blacklist r8188eu.ko" > "/etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf"
exit
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

but when trying to use "make" i got this error:

```
root@kali:/home/hizzly/Documents/tmp/rtl8188eu# make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.6.0-kali2-amd64/build M=/home/hizzly/Documents/tmp/rtl8188eu  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.6.0-kali2-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:155: modules] Error 2
```

I wanted to ask how should fix this issue? I've done almost anything from forums, but nothing happened. I will be so glad if someone help me.

---

@alecxs i used this commands

```
[Download and Installation]
01]  #apt update && apt upgrade]

02] #apt install -y bc linux-headers-amd64


03] #git clone https://github.com/kimocoder/rtl8188eus
or
direct download from :
https://github.com/kimocoder/rtl8188e...


04] #cd rtl8188eus

05] #cp realtek_blacklist.conf /etc/modprobe.d

06] #make
```

this time started but i get other kind of error:

```
home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2204:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_da’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 2204 |   set_fs(get_ds());
      |          ^~~~~~
      |          get_da
/home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2204:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
 2204 |   set_fs(get_ds());
      |          ^~~~~~~~
      |          |
      |          int
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                 from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘int’
   29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘retriveFromFile’:
/home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2242:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
 2242 |    set_fs(get_ds());
      |           ^~~~~~~~
      |           |
      |           int
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                 from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘int’
   29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘storeToFile’:
/home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2277:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
 2277 |    set_fs(get_ds());
      |           ^~~~~~~~
      |           |
      |           int
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                 from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘int’
   29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/scripts/Makefile.build:273: /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/Makefile:1704: /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/Makefile:180: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:2286: modules] Error 2
root@kali:/home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus# make install
install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko  /lib/modules/5.6.0-kali2-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat '8188eu.ko': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:2292: install] Error 1
```

---

after using CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wno-error" make:

```
root@kali:/home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus# CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wno-error" make
    make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.6.0-kali2-amd64/build M=/home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus  modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-amd64'
      CC [M]  /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.o
    In file included from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:30,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
    /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/wifi.h:970: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
      970 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
          | 
    In file included from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service_linux.h:83,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:50,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:27,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
    /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/ieee80211.h:1460: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     1460 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
          | 
    /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘isFileReadable’:
    /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2204:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_da’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     2204 |   set_fs(get_ds());
          |          ^~~~~~
          |          get_da
    /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2204:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
     2204 |   set_fs(get_ds());
          |          ^~~~~~~~
          |          |
          |          int
    In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
                     from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                     from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:27,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
    /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘int’
       29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
          |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
    /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘retriveFromFile’:
    /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2242:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
     2242 |    set_fs(get_ds());
          |           ^~~~~~~~
          |           |
          |           int
    In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
                     from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                     from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:27,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
    /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘int’
       29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
          |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
    /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘storeToFile’:
    /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2277:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
     2277 |    set_fs(get_ds());
          |           ^~~~~~~~
          |           |
          |           int
    In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
                     from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                     from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:27,
                     from /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
    /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘int’
       29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
          |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
    cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
    make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/scripts/Makefile.build:273: /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/Makefile:1704: /home/hizzly/temp/rtl8188eus] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-common/Makefile:180: sub-make] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-amd64'
    make: *** [Makefile:2286: modules] Error 2
```

Comment: is this a question about cross compiling?

Comment: @alecxs no, i just want to turn on monitor mode on my wireless card.before i post here i watched "null-byte",but same thing, when i should use "make" gives me this error.

Comment: i cannot install the driver for "monitor mode" for this wireless card

Comment: try `sudo apt install linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-amd64` https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410109

Comment: try `CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wno-error" make` for step 06]

Comment: @alecxs same thing

Comment: `grep -ir '-Werror' ~/Documents/tmp/rtl8188eus` will give you list of makefiles. remove the `-Werror` flag from CFLAGS. or try `make -k`