# power management not working with realtek wifi card

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, realtek

I'm new on Linux Mint and I have a bug.
I have setup Linux Mint, today, and when I use my internet connection, after 5-10 minutes, my connection stopped. I need to disconnect and connect my wifi card.

If I don't do this, I can't use my connection.

It isn't only on Linux Mint, even with Antergos I'm having this error.
But on Windows (10) it's okay, the problem disappears.

I have a [TP-LINK TL-WN821N up to 300mbps.](http://www.tp-link.fr/products/details/cat-11_TL-WN821N.html)

If I write `iw [Device name] get power_save` on my console I get back: "Power_save : Off".

And on this file : /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

I have "wifi.powersave = 2" ...

lsusb output :

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0032 SiGma Micro 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So, how can I fix this ?

Comment: you may want to have a look at your log files under `/var/log`.

Comment: Welcome to U&L please add the output of `lsusb`

Comment: Message edited with lsusb output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem here is that most of the realtek wifi based chipsets, and specifically the RTL8192CU have hardware firmware, and driver bugs. Power management is brain damaged on that chipset.

Power management does not work well, and it has to be turned off for the chipset to work in minimal operational acceptable settings.

You can read the (lengthy) post for more details here [Wi-Fi problems using ASUS USB-N13 adapter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215)

So in reality you cannot "fix" it, only going for another wifi chipset.

If you are buying a notebook or iOT board that comes with it, I strongly suggest either selecting another model/brand, replacing it with a model compatible with your board, or deactivating the chipset and using an external USB Wifi.

Comment: Okey thanks ! i will just buy a new wifi card !

Comment: @Ahkrin Be sure to read the link, it gives general guidelines how to select a new one.