# TP-Link TL-WN822N wifi dongle under Linux

Tags: wifi, drivers, realtek

I bought a [TP-Link TL-WN822N v4](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN822N_v4) wi-fi dongle, based upon a Realtek RTL8192EU chipset.

It is recognized out of the box on a Linux system, but would not connect to anything (the connections will be very weak, even though the adapter has external antennas).

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved by installing [this alternative driver](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver).

You will need an alternate method of internet connection (such as a wired connection or a tethered phone).

1. Install kernel headers, git and dkms.
2. Clone the repo: `https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git` somewhere in your home directory.
3. Add it to the DKMS: `dkms add .`, then build it with `dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0`.
4. Try loading the new module `8192eu`. If it works, blacklist the broken `rtl8xxxu` module.

Comment: I asked this and answered it myself since I wanted to document what I had done. The info around the internet is mostly Ubuntu/Debian-centric (refers to PPAs, apt-get etc...) and this should at least try to be distro-independent.

Comment: I advise reading this too; realtek are lacking in quality https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: how to get 4th step done?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a very very different answer to this one.
I recommend u do the following and u will be good to go

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManger
```

This will stop the networks manager.

Now,

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

This will restart the network manager. If it doesn't turn on type the last command once more and it will start and start showing your wireless adapter.
My TpLink didn't show up and spend a very long time on various online courses until I tried this and this works perfectly fine.

Always follow Programmers path