# wlp3s0, Interface doesn't support scanning : Invalid argument

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my old laptop,but I can't make wireless connection

```
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up
mm@6830s:~$ sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scan
wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Invalid argument
```

Everything seems to be ok

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:21:00:b2:16:48
       width: 64 bits
```

My interface

```
 cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens5
iface ens5 inet dhcp

auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet dhcp
```

If I go for

```
sudo iw dev wlp3s0 scan
command failed: Invalid argument (-22)
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: The default `wl` driver does not support some of the functionalities of your BCM4312, including monitor mode. I advise you googling for alternatives drivers, probably compiling them. The solution used to be easy in the past. Using kali also can complicate a lot your life, it is good you are using Ubuntu. see also this, while it is a rant about realtek it might be useful https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Obrigado.I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: De nada...Broadcom é barato mas pode não ser a melhor escolha para certas funcionalidades. Pode ser mais prático arranjar uma pen para hacking.

Comment: Use the IProute2 command : `sudo iw dev wlp3s0 scan | grep SSID`