# TL-WN822N wifi not establishing AP mode in armv7l

Tags: drivers, hardware, realtek, hostapd, arch-arm

I'm using odroid-xu4 with dietpi OS. I wished to use TL-WN822N wifi device as a hotspot. So I installed a driver of rtl8192eu by using this https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

It installed correctly. After I installed **hostapd** and **dnsmasq** for it to work as a hotspot , hostapd is not running. It is always showing **"exited"**.

The ifconfig result:

[image]

The iwconfig result:

[image]

My lsusb result:

[image]

My lshw result:

[image]

M hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf result:

[image]

my hostapd.conf file contains:

```
interface=wlan1


driver=nl80211


ssid=WiFi-TV1


hw_mode=g


channel=3


ieee80211n=1


wmm_enabled=1


ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]

macaddr_acl=0


ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

My wifi device details:https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN822N_v4

[image]

My dmesg output:

```
[    7.011912] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  767.652339] usb 3-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci-hcd
[  767.753321] usb 3-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=0108
[  767.753352] usb 3-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  767.753373] usb 3-1.1: Product: 802.11n NIC
[  767.753393] usb 3-1.1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  767.753413] usb 3-1.1: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[  767.839986] usb 3-1.1: This Realtek USB WiFi dongle (0x2357:0x0108) is untested!
[  767.839996] usb 3-1.1: Please report results to Jes.Sorensen@gmail.com
[  767.934329] usb 3-1.1: Vendor: Realtek
[  767.934336] usb 3-1.1: Product: 802.11n NI
[  767.934341] usb 3-1.1: Serial:
[  767.934347] usb 3-1.1: rtl8192eu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[  767.934354] usb 3-1.1: 00: 29 81 00 7c 01 40 03 00
[  767.934359] usb 3-1.1: 08: 40 74 04 50 14 00 00 00
[  767.934364] usb 3-1.1: 10: 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2b 2c 2c
[  767.934369] usb 3-1.1: 18: 2b 2c 2c f2 ef ef ff ff
[  767.934374] usb 3-1.1: 20: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934379] usb 3-1.1: 28: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934384] usb 3-1.1: 30: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934389] usb 3-1.1: 38: ff ff 29 29 28 28 28 28
[  767.934394] usb 3-1.1: 40: 28 28 28 28 28 f2 ef ef
[  767.934399] usb 3-1.1: 48: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934404] usb 3-1.1: 50: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934408] usb 3-1.1: 58: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934413] usb 3-1.1: 60: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934418] usb 3-1.1: 68: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934423] usb 3-1.1: 70: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934428] usb 3-1.1: 78: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934433] usb 3-1.1: 80: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934438] usb 3-1.1: 88: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934442] usb 3-1.1: 90: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934447] usb 3-1.1: 98: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934452] usb 3-1.1: a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934457] usb 3-1.1: a8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934462] usb 3-1.1: b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934466] usb 3-1.1: b8: a1 3e 1d 00 00 00 ff ff
[  767.934472] usb 3-1.1: c0: ff 01 00 10 00 00 00 ff
[  767.934476] usb 3-1.1: c8: 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934481] usb 3-1.1: d0: 57 23 08 01 e7 47 02 7c
[  767.934486] usb 3-1.1: d8: 8b ca 18 08 62 0a 03 52
[  767.934491] usb 3-1.1: e0: 65 61 6c 74 65 6b 20 0e
[  767.934495] usb 3-1.1: e8: 03 38 30 32 2e 31 31 6e
[  767.934500] usb 3-1.1: f0: 20 4e 49 43 20 00 00 ff
[  767.934505] usb 3-1.1: f8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934510] usb 3-1.1: 100: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934515] usb 3-1.1: 108: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934519] usb 3-1.1: 110: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0d
[  767.934524] usb 3-1.1: 118: 03 00 05 00 30 00 00 00
[  767.934529] usb 3-1.1: 120: 00 93 ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934534] usb 3-1.1: 128: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934539] usb 3-1.1: 130: f6 a8 98 2d 03 92 98 00
[  767.934543] usb 3-1.1: 138: fc 8c 00 11 9b 44 02 0a
[  767.934548] usb 3-1.1: 140: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934553] usb 3-1.1: 148: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934558] usb 3-1.1: 150: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934562] usb 3-1.1: 158: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934567] usb 3-1.1: 160: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934572] usb 3-1.1: 168: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934577] usb 3-1.1: 170: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934582] usb 3-1.1: 178: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934586] usb 3-1.1: 180: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934591] usb 3-1.1: 188: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934596] usb 3-1.1: 190: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934601] usb 3-1.1: 198: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934605] usb 3-1.1: 1a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934610] usb 3-1.1: 1a8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934615] usb 3-1.1: 1b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934620] usb 3-1.1: 1b8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934624] usb 3-1.1: 1c0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934629] usb 3-1.1: 1c8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934634] usb 3-1.1: 1d0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934639] usb 3-1.1: 1d8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934643] usb 3-1.1: 1e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934648] usb 3-1.1: 1e8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934653] usb 3-1.1: 1f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934658] usb 3-1.1: 1f8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  767.934664] usb 3-1.1: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[  767.934670] usb 3-1.1: RTL8192EU MAC: 7c:8b:ca:18:08:62
[  767.934676] usb 3-1.1: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[  767.939193] usb 3-1.1: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin failed with error -2
[  767.939203] usb 3-1.1: request_firmware(rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin) failed
[  767.939210] usb 3-1.1: Fatal - failed to load firmware
[  767.939241] rtl8xxxu: probe of 3-1.1:1.0 failed with error -11
[  767.939286] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
```

Comment: Avoid realtek. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: Try driver=rtl871xdrv

Comment: Error obtained: **Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Line 6: invalid/unknown driver 'rtl871xdrv'
1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Failed to initialize interface
**@Rui F Riberiro

Comment: Thanks. Bear in mind not all combo of drivers/wifi sticks provide AP mode and monitor mode. That is a research that has to be done *before* buying one.

Comment: This device works well in raspberrypi as a AP mode. It also works well in ubuntu 16.04.1 as a AP mode. @Rui F Riberiro

Comment: A combo of driver/wifi chipset/hostapd version.

Comment: hosapd version: v2.3