# No wifi adapter found ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

[image]I had bought a new hp laptop with windows 10 and dual booted it with ubuntu 18.04 since two days wifi is not working when I go in the setting it says no wifi adapter found and one more problem when turn my bluetooth on somehow airplane mode turns on bluetooth is not working

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]

Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]

Kernel modules: wl
```

output of `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904] (rev 08)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07)

00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)

00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)

00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)

00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d10] (rev f1)

00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9d14] (rev f1)

00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:9d15] (rev f1)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48] (rev 21)

00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)

00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)

01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] [1002:6660] (rev 83)

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
```

Please tell me how to fix it

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the `rtl8723de` driver is recently provided to linux system.

Comment: @GAD3R Despite added or not added, they are all problematic.

Comment: I recently found out that WiFi adapters are worse than video cards after mine stopped working after a couple of years when the firmware got removed from Ubuntu. If you don't find a solution quickly, you might want to return the notebook. USB WiFi adapters supposedly work, but the two I've tried so far don't. https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Category:Linux_driver/802dot11 may prove helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Following this worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Clone this repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

Enter the cloned folder:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
```

Checkout the extended branch:

```
git checkout extended
```

Start installation:

```
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```