# Realtek Wifi interface is not stable in Kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, realtek, nmcli

I have a kali linux system(VM) and I added realtek wireless adapter to it and same is detecting as a wireless interface

```
ip address
[...]
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:14:5b:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

uname -a
Linux kali 4.17.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.17.17-1kali1 (2018-08-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux

iwconfig

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

And when I am trying to see available networks using below command , it was showing SSIDs ocassionally

```
nmcli device wifi list
*  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
nmcli device wifi list
*  SSID                    MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
   praveen-IAP             Infra  149   54 Mbit/s  92      ▂▄▆█  WEP
   Yoda-d21f-G1-Guest      Infra  149   35 Mbit/s  92      ▂▄▆█
   vin_guest               Infra  149   35 Mbit/s  92      ▂▄▆█
   clarityCP               Infra  149   12 Mbit/s  92      ▂▄▆█
   [....]

nmcli device wifi list
*  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
```

And when I am trying to use wpa_supplicant ,I am getting below error

```
root@kali:~/wpa3# ./wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c sandeep-wpa3-sae.conf  -ddd
wpa_supplicant v2.7-devel-hostap_2_6-1842-gfa617ee+
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Initializing interface 'wlan0' conf 'sandeep-wpa3-sae.conf' driver 'default' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file 'sandeep-wpa3-sae.conf' -> '/root/wpa3/sandeep-wpa3-sae.conf'
Reading configuration file '/root/wpa3/sandeep-wpa3-sae.conf'
ctrl_interface='DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant'
update_config=1
Line: 3 - start of a new network block
key_mgmt: 0x400
ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=8):
     54 65 73 74 57 50 41 33                           TestWPA3
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=8): [REMOVED]
pairwise: 0x10
ieee80211w=1 (0x1)
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='TestWPA3'
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 3 to mode 2: -19 (No such device)
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
Failed to add interface wlan0
wlan0: Cancelling scan request
wlan0: Cancelling authentication timeout
```

`lsusb -v` output

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0xa811
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
  iSerial                 3 00e04c000001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           60
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           6
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x09  EP 9 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           12
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: Please read the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: maybe you could tell which realtek chip you have. Realtek maintains dozens of different chipset some being well known for not working properly on Linux (making it even harder to use on Kali)

Comment: @Kiwy:  updated description with `lsusb` output

Comment: Please edit your question, comments are here to ask for clarification but not here to contains important piece of information. By the way this doesn't indicate us the chipset your usb realtek card is using. maybe the use of lsusb -vv could help to get relevant information.

Comment: @Kiwy : updated `lsusb -v` output

Comment: I've edited your quesiton to remove a lot of useless information. Keep in mind that the longer your post is the longer it takes to answer and the most likely people will close your post because Question regarding Kali should show a great understanding of the problem. Also the comment of Rui F Ribeiro is correct and point you toward the right direction.