# Realtek rtl8821ce wifi drivers for Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers, realtek

I tried installing the endlessm and tomaspinho drivers because they're the only ones being suggested on here and the rest of the internet but I haven't been able to compile them. Does anyone here have any different options I might look into?

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro So I should buy a new wifi adapter or just give up? Great, guess I'll go back to Windows.

Comment: "I haven't been able to compile them". Why? give us something to work with...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. Apparantly I just had to update my kernel to the latest version.