# Wifi hotspot: very slow download/upload speed

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi-hotspot

Linux Mint 19.1. **Wired** connection: down 85.30Mb, up 83.59Mb. Wifi **Hotspot**: down 0.78Mb, up 9.70Mb. Why so slow?? I want more speed.

My connection settings: [image] [image]

On my Windows 10 1903 I'm getting 60Mb/55Mb results. If that's a typical Linux problem and there's no solution for that - OK, that would be the answer. But please give me a proof (links, notes in docs, etc.).

I found a bunch of other questions like this here on AskUbuntu. No solution though. Please help.

I've just changed 'band' to 5GHz. No effect.

Comment: did you provide all of the available information?

Comment: How did you measure the bandwitdth?

Comment: the AR9462 is a 802.11n chipset, no 5GHz band there. AFAIR is also a quite cheap and old chipset. As why a hotspot/portal could be slow, it depends on a lot of factors, there is not enough data on the question for answering that. see this related answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter-realtek

Comment: @Panki, via speedtest.org.

Comment: @Rui F Rubeiro,  I readed through that answer. So what do I need to do? Buy new firmware? Replace my drivers? And what kind of info do you need? Drivers, again?

Comment: @jsotola, what kind of info do you need? Drivers? Firmware?