# Wifi keeps reconnecting and asking for passphrase in Manjaro XFCE

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, manjaro, broadcom

I'm connecting to a local WiFi network with a normal setup (see system specs below), that is a Fritz!Box router and a WiFi repeater to increase range. Usually all is well, I have a normal connection and can access the internet. However, sometimes seemingly at random (but maybe more often after suspension?!), the NetworkManager gui kicks me out of the WiFi and asks me for the passphrase. As it already knows it, I just press enter, but then it keeps asking me again and again. That forces me to press enter repeatedly like 10-20 times. And then, at random again, it connects. This happens like 20-30 times a day and is really distracting. Any idea what the problem is? Maybe it is the WiFi repeater setup where there are two networks with the same name? But even if I'm only in the range of the router itself but not the repeater I get the problem...

Important to add: *I don't have this problem with any other device* (e.g. mobile phones, tablets, a laptop running windows)

**What I found so far:** I've found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032703/wifi-frequently-disconnecting-timeout) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts) post and I've tried the following:

- set `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` to `wifi.powersave = 2` (but this breaks NetworkManager, i.e. `systemctl status NetworkManager.service`yields status `failed`)
- following `journalctl -fu NetworkManager` to see what errors it gives me

If the connection fails, `journalctl -fu NetworkManager` gives me:

```
[...]
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key 
device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
dhcp4 (wlp2s0):  canceled DHCP transaction
dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
dhcp6 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
[...]
```

And when hitting enter to the dialog asking me the passphrase, it states the following:

```
device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'my_home_wifi' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
[... some stuff here about "Config: added"]
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

and it begins again asking me for the passphrase...

My system specs: `Manjaro 4.19.122-1` with xfce. My wireless card is a `Broadcom BCM4313` (running with the `broadcom-wl` driver)

Comment: see, related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter-realtek/252215#252215 and https://superuser.com/questions/1311149/why-do-wifi-routers-do-such-a-bad-job-of-channel-selection/1312062#1312062

Answer (score 1):

I myself have had this kind of trouble with Broadcom chips in the past. You might try a different driver such as the reverse-engineered `b43` driver or `brcmfmac`. Former should be available on the AUR. Latter should be built into the kernel.

See here for further reading: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#Installation

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have actually looked into the WiFi chip problem before, but dismissed it and thought it might be a problem with the NetworkManager instead... Unfortunately, I have never figured out a good solution for my Broadcom chip. Or the current one should already be the best?! Anyways, I'll look into this again...

Comment: Do not discount also layer 2 issues. 2.4GHz is problematic in big cities/large campus. See my comment in the main question. +1