# Unable to connect to Wi-FI on Linux Lite

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I have a TP Link USB WLAN adapter. The device supports `Wi-Fi 4{802.11n}`.

There is a text file in the disc that came with the device that says:

> For users using the Linux System, they should head over to the official website and download the driver.

So I did exactly that. There was a driver `binary file` in a `bin` folder, the guide said I should type `sudo make` to compile the driver and `sudo make install` to install the driver. So the driver was installed successfully. Every time I reboot the computer and try to connect to a Wi-Fi network, the connection is successful but I cannot connect to the internet and when I disconnect from the hotspot, it cannot again, no matter how many times I retry.

The model of the USB WLAN Adapter is TLWN823N manufactured by TPLink.

Please help me.

Comment: TLWN823N, 15 year tech, realtek rebranded junk see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter-realtek/252215#252215